# #2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)

Tags: mysql, local

I am trying to study how stuff works in mysql.

This is under localhost using wamp. So I renamed ibdata1 in the mysql data folder, and restarted. Mysql will automatically create a new ibdata1 file.I start phpmyadmin and I saw this error. So i delete the new ibdata1 and paste the old ibdata1(the one I renamed, i rename it back to ibdata1 and paste it on mysql data folder), and I still see this error. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem, i searched the web and found out that mysqld is not running, what i did is i opened the mysql and mysqld from the mysql directory, and checked if the mysqld and mysql processes are running, then i tried to connect..